# Is TabNet's mask explanation biased?

Tags: neural-network, google-cloud-ai

I have been reading about [TabNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07442.pdf) model and it's predictions "explanations" through the attentive transformers' masks values.

However, if the inputs values are not normalized, aren't this masks values simply a normalization scalar (and not a feature's importance value)?

E.g.: A feature `Time` is expressed in days and has a mask mean value of 1/365, it could mean that the mask is simply normalizing the feature?

Let me know if I wasn't clear in my question.